# How to update Dot Net Maui Windows Application from a remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, maui, msix

I have been working on an Application for the past 3 months and I'm currently doing beta testing. My only issue is I do not know how to make the application auto-update from a remote server, so that I do not have to physically update each computer with the newest version of the application. In my old WinForms application I was able to download and install a package to auto update from a remote FTP server. Any help is welcomed.

I tried following the documentation on the Microsoft website; [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162637/how-to-configure-auto-update-in-maui-application)
and also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web) but i was unable to figure it out.

Comment: instead of vaguely saying "unable to figure it out" why don't you tell us what **specific** problems you ran into when trying to follow the documentation?

Comment: In one of your links, there is an answer that links to [App Installer file update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings). Did you attempt that? The link I just gave then links to [Update non-Store published app packages from your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/non-store-developer-updates?source=recommendations).

Comment: AutoUpdate for an embedded *.appinstaller is even better. The separate .appinstaller file is good for admins defining rules for their enterprise. The embedded .appinstaller enables a dev to provide the same benefits as part of the .msix itself :-)